# Induction proof done, need to simplify $\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^5}\ln(1 + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \leq 4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{n+1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, induction

Prove that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt[4]{j^5}\ln(1+\frac{1}{j^2}) \leq 4 \sqrt[4]{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} $$

I got everything right and came up with an inequality:

$$\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^5} \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) \leq 4  \sqrt[4]{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$

The problem is I cannot simplify that to get my solution all done. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Hi, there's no need to edit or attempt to delete your questions once you've got answer. You can just leave them be.

Answer (score 1):

As regards your final step, just notice that $\ln(1+x)\leq x$.Therefore it suffices to show that
$$\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^5}\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 4  \sqrt[4]{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$
that is
$$\sqrt[4]{n}\leq 4 (n+1)^{\frac{1}{4}+2-\frac{5}{4}}=4(n+1)$$
which trivially holds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you mean by simplify it.

Anyways, in case the last part of the induction part is required, given your inequality and the induction hipothesys you would have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sqrt[4]{j^5}\ln\biggl(1+\frac{1}{j^2}\biggr)\le 4\sqrt[4]{n}+\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^5}\ln\biggl(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)\le$$
$$\le 4\sqrt[4]{n}+4\sqrt[4]{\frac{n+1}{n}}\stackrel{n\ge 1}{\le\le\le}4\sqrt[4]{n}+4\sqrt[4]{n+1}\le 4\sqrt[4]{n+1}\mbox,$$
just as we wanted.